# How to accept an input in a sty file?

Tags: packages

I have a [sty](https://github.com/benjcabalona1029/MAMathematics2021/blob/main/LectureNoteTemplate/itaewon.sty) file that lets me create a definition box. My code looks like this

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{itaewon}[2021/02/21 Boxed for Definition,Theorems etc.]

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=subsection]{DefinitionBox}[3][]{
        arc=5mm,
        lower separated=false,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        colbacktitle=blue!10,
        coltitle=blue!50!black,
        enhanced,
        attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
                yshift=-2mm},
        colframe=blue!50!black,
        colback=blue!10,
        overlay={
        \node[draw=blue!50!black,thick,
        %inner sep=2mm,
        fill= blue!10,rounded corners=1mm, 
        yshift=0pt, 
        xshift=-0.5cm, 
        left, 
        text=blue!50!black,
        anchor=east,
        font=\bfseries] 
        at (frame.north east) {#3};},
        overlay={
        \node[draw=blue!50!black,thick,
        %inner sep=2mm,
        fill= blue!10,rounded corners=1mm, 
        yshift=0pt, 
        xshift=-0.5cm, 
        left, 
        text=blue!50!black,
        anchor=east,
        font=\bfseries] 
        at (frame.north east) {#3};},
        title=#2 \thetcbcounter,#1
                                }
```

I want to have some sort of logic, i.e. when the title is `{TheoremBox}` I want the `colbacktitle=green!10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\DefineBoxFor}[2][black]{
    \expandafter\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=subsection]{#2Box}[3][]{
            arc=5mm,
            lower separated=false,
            fonttitle=\bfseries,
            colbacktitle=#1!10,
            coltitle=#1!50!black,
            enhanced,
            attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,
                    yshift=-2mm},
            colframe=#1!50!black,
            colback=#1!10,
            overlay={
            \node[draw=#1!50!black,thick,
            %inner sep=2mm,
            fill= #1!10,rounded corners=1mm, 
            yshift=0pt, 
            xshift=-0.5cm, 
            left, 
            text=#1!50!black,
            anchor=east,
            font=\bfseries] 
            at (frame.north east) {##3};},
            overlay={
            \node[draw=#1!50!black,thick,
            %inner sep=2mm,
            fill= #1!10,rounded corners=1mm, 
            yshift=0pt, 
            xshift=-0.5cm, 
            left, 
            text=#1!50!black,
            anchor=east,
            font=\bfseries] 
            at (frame.north east) {##3};},
            title=##2 \thetcbcounter,##1
        }
}
\DefineBoxFor[blue]{Definition}
\DefineBoxFor[green]{Theorem}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{DefinitionBox}{Definition}{description}
    Some text
\end{DefinitionBox}

\begin{TheoremBox}{Theorem}{description}
    Some text
\end{TheoremBox}

\end{document}
```

Here the command `\DefineBoxFor` is used to define `...Box` environments. For example, in the above code,

```
\DefineBoxFor[blue]{Definition}
\DefineBoxFor[green]{Theorem}
```

defines `DefinitionBox` and `TheoremBox`, with color blue and green respectively (`##1,##2,##3` is the parameter of the `...Box` environment.). This is simpler than defining them separately.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.